# Is OAuth token-based authentication tied to a physical machine or to the private key?

Tags: ssl, oauth, oauth-2.0, openssl

I've set up an OAuth authentication between my computer and a server. I did the OAuth dance and have generated and obtained the keys/secrets required to access private data from the server with OAuth.

I was wondering if there is anything restricting me from using the OAuth keys on another machine?

In other words could I just copy the private key and resource owner key/secrets to another machine and use it to authenticate with the server with OAuth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can use them on another machine to perform authentication. OAuth is not tied to any machine. Consider your Google/FB login, you can authenticate from any machine.